# jquery shake doesn't work on divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, shake

I was designing a webpage and needed JQuery shake to shake some divs but i couldn't  get it to work so I guessed it maybe is something in my page which was preventing it. then I used it on two very simple divs but again it didn't work.
[Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/Lm56byke/29/)
Unfortunately I fail to notice what is wrong exactly.
thanks in advance.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("div > div").on("click", function() {
    $("div > div").effect("shake", {
      times: 10
    }, 100);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need https://jqueryui.com/ for `.effect` function to be available.

http://jsfiddle.net/1Lp7aoue/